# how to track language changes in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, localization

I'm new in developing  iOS app. So I've recently faced a problem with localization of my app. I would like to perform some actions in response to language change in system settings. 
To get language ID I use

```
[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

in *applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method. First time it returns language ID right (e.g. "en" for English).  Then, I close my application (or send it to background) and change language to German. After that I restart my app, but instead of "de", it still returns "en". I think my app might probably store old settings somewhere... but where exactly? How to retrieve valid current value?

Comment: I found the source of my problem. It was iOS Simulator. I installed my app on device and all problems disappeared.

Comment: if this solution solved your problem then you should write an answer to your question and accept it as the correct answer (not only a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of my problem. It was iOS Simulator. I installed my app on device and all problems disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this old answer:

[Getting current device language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios)

**EDIT:**

```
NSString *testLang = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *testLang1 = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *testLang2 = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:2];
NSString *testLang3 = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *testLang4 = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:4];
NSLog(@"LINGUA SYS:%@:%@:%@:%@:%@",testLang,testLang1,testLang2,testLang3,testLang4);
```

in debugger console:

LINGUA SYS:en:it:fr:de:ja

or:

LINGUA SYS:es:en:it:fr:de

or:

LINGUA SYS:pt-PT:en:es:it:fr

so the code you posted is right, the error should be somewhere else...

Comment: I had done some homework before decided to ask my question.  I had read that topic. It's useful, but does not solve my problem. The call  '[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];' returns the same value before and after language change. I tested this function in small test app, and it worked correctly... But still I cannot understand, why it doesn't work in my main application. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user68...: mhm, that's has no sense to me... i tried your line of code and it changes the returned value correctly, and so if i ask for objectAtIndex:1 (or 2, 3...) i get always "en" for 1 (not in case en is in 0, of course) and then for 2, 3... the language i had in 0 before my last change... so the error for you may be somewhere else... are you sure you are checking it in the right way, where do you put the value you get form that line of code? i add new edit in my answer...

Comment: To my mind the problem is in some project settings. I found another topic with similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294597/how-to-prevent-need-for-rebuilding-app-after-changing-language-region)

Comment: yes, i do agree... could you post a capture of your app-info.plist?

Comment: I posted a screenshot here [screenshot of .plist](http://img683.imageshack.us/i/plistscreenshot.png/)

Comment: ...similar to mine... sorry, it should work... did you try the "NSLocalizedString" way? NSLocalizedString(@"Lang", @""); (you need to localize a text file called "Localizable.strings") with this content:/* Lang */
"Lang" = "eng"; (<- for the english file... change "eng" with "ita", "fr"... for every lang you intend to support...)

Comment: Yes, I did, It was a part of my task. I have Localizable.strings files for four languages. But I need to rebuild my app to force my app to change language. I also localized the name of my app and splash screen and they work correctly without rebuilding. It is getting a bit clearer now. I will try to find out where my app saves the value of current language and why it does this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like that:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en",@"es", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

the value is stored on NSUSerDefaults and changes on settings don't apply.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but read the comment to my question. I've already solved this problem.